# PCIe card powered but not recognized on custom interface

Tags: integrated-circuit, communication, linux, pcie, digital-communications

I have a black magic declink mini recorder card that I am trying to recognize on a small form factor linux machine (debian 3.2.46-1 x86_64).  I have made a custom interface board with what I think are the critical connections.  When I boot the machine, the card definitely powers on, I can feel the heat on the chip, however, the OS does not recognize it.  It is not a driver problem, they are loaded.  I have tested the card with the same MOBO on another custom interface and it works fine.  Here is what I have connected:

+12V

+3.3V

SMCLK

SMDATA

GND

TX+

TX-

Rx+

Rx-

PWRGOOD

REFCLK+/-

Hot plug presence detect 1 & 2 (PRSNT#1, PRSNT#2) - these are shorted to eachother.  I believe it is to detect when a card is fully plugged into the port as they are at the furthest ends of the card.

SMCLK and SMDAT are optional from what I read here: http://www.pcisig.com/specifications/pciexpress/technical_library/dev_con_09_02/specifications/pciexpress/PCIExpress_Cards.pdf

I got the pinout of the card here: http://pinouts.ru/Slots/pci_express_pinout.shtml

In order to check if it is recognized, I check lspci and lsmod for blackmagic.  On the other custom board, it was recognized fine and showed up in lspci and lsmod.

I don't think it is a differential pair problem as I have not had problems with USB 3.0 of LAN on the same board.

Comment: This is about how to use a PCIe appliance, and is off topic here

Comment: I am physically wiring pins on the PCIe card to a breadboard.  I thought someone might have been in a similar situation before and could share some tips.

Comment: Unless you can see the card with lspci then nothing else in the os matters (lsmod, drivers, etc).  You say "On the other custom board, it was recognized..."  Not sure what that means?  Do you have two of the same systems you're trying to debug, or is the "other board" an entirely different design?  Can you tell us more about what you mean by "custom interface board".  Is it a PCB?  My first thought is that you need to take care with the high-speed serial i/o (TX & RX signals).

Comment: Need a pic of this 'custom interface'.  The TX and RX connections must be controlled impedance due to the signalling rate.  Anything else and the link will almost certainly not come up correctly.